# Run a bash command in gnome-terminal

Tags: bash

I have a simple two line script. First variable contains a list of directories which will added to music-lib script, which will be called by gnome-terminal with bash command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dirName=( "${@}" )
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "music-lib ${dirName[@]}; exec bash"
```

When i try to send array to gnome-terminal with execute bash command it does nothing. It just appears on a few seconds and all. But when i change dirName variable to something like this

```
dirName=( "${*}" )
```

Gnome-terminal is appeared. But i don't need set dirName variable as a string, because music-lib script expects array. As i understand, there is something wrong with array in bash command. Single quote dirName variable helps, but only if directory does not contain any spaces.

Comment: Did you try with `gnome-terminal -- bash -c "music-lib \"${dirName[@]}\"; exec bash"`?

Comment: yep, gives exactly same result

Comment: What does `music-lib` do?

Comment: it just create hard links for music-files in directory which i sync with my DAP. I can say, that i have problem with any command with array, when i use bash -c ".....". For example, i have removed "gnome-terminal" command and replace music-lib script with simple echo. And i still have problem with array output.

Comment: I don't think gnome-terminal is relevant. If I simply do `bash -c "echo music-lib ${dirName[@]}"` it only echoes the first element of the array.

Comment: But if I change it to `bash -c "echo \"music-lib ${dirName[*]}\""` it echoes the whole array.

Comment: Or even `bash -c 'echo music-lib $@' -- "${dirName[@]}"`

Comment: so, if i do something like music-lib "${@}" without calling bash -c "..." it works as expected. I still can not understand the root of the problem.

Comment: @One: The problem is how arrays are interpolated in double quotes. The expansion happens even before `bash -c` is called, so only the first element becomes part of the `-c` command, the rest is passed as argument list to bash itself.

Comment: it seems, if i do something like this gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'music-lib "${@}"' -- "${dirName[@]}", it works

Comment: The root of the problem is that `"$@"` splits into multiple strings. You want to run `bash -c "music-lib file1 file2 file3; exec bash"` but instead you run `bash -c "music-lib file1" "file2" "file3; exec bash"`. choroba 's suggestion is ideal.

Comment: @thatotherguy : True, but can this explain, why in the first case the terminal immediately closes? No matter what `music-lib` is doing, the `exec bash` afterwards should replace the process inside the terminal by an interactive bash.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes. `bash -c "music-lib file1"` does not have a `exec bash` in its command. One of the arguments to the shell is `file3; exec bash`, but it's not part of a command to run.

Comment: @thatotherguy : Hmmm.... The OPs command basically says `bash -c "music-lib SOMETHING; exec bash"`, so the _exec_ is still within the double-quotes, so it should be part of the command. Did I miss something?

Comment: @user1934428 As mentioned `"$@"` splits into multiple strings. The `exec` is within *some* double quotes, but now in a different argument from the string that contains the command. Try `set -- file1 file2 file3; printf 'One argument: %s\n' bash -c "music-lib $@; exec bash"` compared to with `$*`

Comment: @thatotherguy : Thanks. After I reproduced your instructive example **and** also did `set -x` to see how the quoting is done, I start to understand what's going on. Seemingly, my understanding of `"$@"` was ways too simplistic .....